Examples for Span compression
Need help on span compression.currently we are using 8.13 and would like to understand span compression as it reduce overhead on cluster.
As part of eligibility I read exit spans are eligible.
In elastic how can we identify exit spans ?
What are the example for span compression..how can we see it in UI ?
Could u please get some example for better understanding of this feature.
Span compression enabled and with exact match. Would like to see which kinds of transaction getting compressed. Need live examples.

Some one please help here
